# How do I ignore some HTML parts (such as header, menu, footer) from my Solr index?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have been using Nutch + Solr (4.3.0) to index a site, with the schema.xml provided by Nutch.

My problem is that when I do a search that includes some words that occur on my header or menu, Solr responds with all pages, obviously.

What I want is to remove these HTML blocks from the index so that the search doesn't include those 'false positives' so to speak.

I was trying something like:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
      pattern="HEADER STARTS(.*?)HEADER ENDS" replacement="" />
```

applied to the index analyzer of my content fieldType, being "HEADER STARTS/ENDS" HTML comments, but it appears to have no effect at all.

I couldn't find anything better googling... but I am a real newbie to this tech stack.

Any help would be welcome!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you looked at HTMLStripCharFilterFactory? (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory)

Comment: In fact I have but I think this filter only removes html tags and other stuff, but the content stays... Take a look at the samples. In my case it would just remove the two comments, but not the content in between, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.

Comment: You can take a look at my answer below : [Removing menu's from html during crawl or indexing with nutch and solr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38982576/1500564)

Answer (score 2):

you might have a look at [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It is a java library specifically suited for that issue. I used in a project with good results, but I used it with plain Lucene. For Solr integration, there is [an open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3808)

Comment: This lib looks great!!

Answer (score 1):

The [NUTCH-585](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585) which was committed and should be available with the trunk and latest Nutch version should suffice your needs.